# Pandas and the best method for representing variable-length time-series

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, time-series, multi-index

Here's the scenario. Let's say I have data from a visual psychophysics experiment, in which a subject indicates whether the net direction of motion in a noisy visual stimulus is to the left or to the right. The atomic unit here is a single trial and a typical daily session might have between 1000 and 2000 trials. With each trial are associated various parameters: the difficulty of that trial, where stimuli were positioned on the computer monitor, the speed of motion, the distance of the subject from the display, whether the subject answered correctly, etc. For now, let's assume that each trial has only one value for each parameter (e.g., each trial has only one speed of motion, etc.). So far, so easy: trial ids are the Index and the different parameters correspond to columns.

Here's the wrinkle. With each trial are also associated variable length time series. For instance, each trial will have eye movement data that's sampled at 1 kHz (so we get time of acquisition, the x data at that time point, and y data at that time point). Because each trial has a different total duration, the length of these time series will differ across trials.

So... what's the best means for representing this type of data in a pandas DataFrame? Is this something that pandas can even be expected to deal with? Should I go to multiple DataFrames, one for the single valued parameters and one for the time series like parameters?

I've considered adopting a MultiIndex approach where level 0 corresponds to trial number and level 1 corresponds to time of continuous data acquisition. Then all I'd need to do is repeat the single valued columns to match the length of the time series on that trial. But I immediately foresee 2 problems. First, the number of single valued columns is large enough that extending each one of them to match the length of the time series seems very wasteful if not impractical. Second, and more importantly, if I wanna do basic groupby type of analyses (e.g. getting the proportion of correct responses at a given difficulty level), this will give biased (incorrect) results because whether each trial was correct or wrong will be repeated as many times as necessary for its length to match the length of time series on that trial (which is irrelevant to the computation of the mean across trials).

I hope my question makes sense and thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close because I don't this a good question for StackOverflow, it's too big...

Comment: ...that said, I'm dealing with similar data at the moment (also in Psychology, also using eyetracking). I keep all my single-valued trial info in one dataframe, and all my timestamped eye-tracking data in another, indexed by time. When analysing the eye data, for each trial I grab the relevant portion of the eyedata (this can be as simple as `eyedata[trial_start_time:trial_end_time]` if the data is indexed by timestamp) and calculate the relevant vars for that trial, e.g. time in the AoI. Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Vote to leave it open. Just because a question is pretty hard and you don't know the answer, is no reason whatsoever to close it. This is perfectly [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I and one other person also want to know the answer on this.

Comment: I don't understand your second issue: doing groupby gives biased results because the outcome is repeated/extended to pad. But if this is an issue, you can store it in a separate table and do SQL join.

Comment: I don't understand your second issue: doing groupby gives biased results because the outcome is repeated/extended to pad. (Did you mean you only store the outcome once, at the end of the timeseries?) Anyway if this is an issue, you can store the outcome in a separate table and do SQL join. Or, you could backfill the outcome column everywhere except the last row with NAs after padding it.

Comment: You could also take care of the duplicated outcome values by doing something like ``df.outcome.unique()``.

Answer (score 0):

I've also just been dealing with this type of issue. I have a bunch of motion-capture data that I've recorded, containing x- y- and z-locations of several motion-capture markers at time intervals of 10ms, but there are also a couple of single-valued fields per trial (e.g., which task the subject is doing).

I've been using this project as a motivation for learning about `pandas` so I'm certainly not "fluent" yet with it. But I have found it incredibly convenient to be able to concatenate data frames for each trial into a single larger frame for, e.g., one subject:

```
subject_df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(t) for t in subject_trials],
    keys=[i for i, _ in enumerate(subject_trials)])
```

Anyway, my suggestion for how to combine single-valued trial data with continuous time recordings is to duplicate the single-valued columns down the entire index of your time recordings, like you mention toward the end of your question.

The only thing you lose by denormalizing your data in this way is that your data will consume more memory; however, provided you have sufficient memory, I think the benefits are worth it, because then you can do things like group individual time frames of data by the per-trial values. This can be especially useful with a stacked data frame!

As for removing the duplicates for doing, e.g., trial outcome analysis, it's really straightforward to do this:

```
df.outcome.unique()
```

assuming your data frame has an "outcome" column.